# Количество "особенных"елементов массива. С++

Tags: c++, циклы, матрицы

Дана действительная матрица А размерности MxN.Определить количество "особенных" елементов(елемент есть особенным, если он больше чем сумма остальных в своем столбце).
Я знаю что нужно остановиться на последнем елементе в стобце, и пройтись циклом по столбцу выполняя проверку`if(arr[i][j]>count-arr[i][j])` а потом пойти на следующий столбец, но я не знаю как в коде реализовать

```
#include <iostream>

    /* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    {
    int N,M;
    int count=0;
    int kil=0;

    cout<<"vved kol strochek";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<"vved kol stolpzov";
    cin>>M;


int **arr = new int*[N];
for (int i(0); i < M; i++){
    arr[i] = new int[M];
 }
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++ )
    {
      for (int i=0;i<M;i++)
      {

    cout<<" arr["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=";
    cin>>arr[i][j];
  }
}
cout<<"matrizia"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++ )
{
  for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
  {

    cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
for(int j=0;j<N;j++ )
{
  for (int i=0;i<M;i++)
  {
    count=count+arr[i][j];//sum
    cout<<"sum="<<count<<endl;

    if(arr[i][j]>count-arr[i][j])
    {

        kil+=1;
      }


  }
}
cout<<endl;

cout<<"kol osobennih elem of mas="<<kil;

system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Покажите где нужно остановиться. И отформатируйте код пожалуйста.

Comment: @, мое мнение, что нужно остановиться на последнем елементе в стобце, и пройтись циклом по столбцу выполняя проверку`if(arr[i][j]>count-arr[i][j]) `, но я не знаю как в коде реализовать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы не делать за вас домашку поясню на словах, без кода.

Просто подумайте логически: если элемент больше чем сумма других в колонке, то он точно наибольший из всех. Следовательно нужно искать наибольший, попутно подсчитывая сумму других элементов. Как искать наибольший элемент, надеюсь знаете... Ну ладно, вот так это делается:

```
auto maximum = array[0];
for(size_t i = 1; i < array_size; ++i)
{
    if(maximum > array[i])
    {
        maximum = array[i];
    }
}
```

Так вот, нужно модифицировать этот алгоритм так, чтобы при обходе колонки, найдя очередной наибольший элемент запомнить, а предыдущий наибольший прибавить к сумме элементов. Если очередной элемент не наибольший, то просто прибавить его к сумме. После обхода колонки, собственно проверить не больше ли наибольший суммы которую вы получили.